# Using Mercurial, is it possible to see multiple commits in a PR (Pull Request)?

Tags: mercurial, phabricator

Using git and GitHub, I was able to work on one feature, using a branch, and commit and push, let's say 12 commits to a PR (Pull Request) on GitHub, and then reviewers can see the final diff with all 12 commits, or see each commit, so as to see how I made it barely working, and then each refinement one after another. (or maybe bug fix or refactoring).

However, at my company now, we are using Mercurial, and it seems I have to use `hg amend` to do it. But this way, the intermediate commits cannot be viewed independently.

If I commit one after another, the diff would show up as 2 or more Diffs, instead of one big diff for the PR. I cannot really ask team members to review my PR by going through 12 Diffs so I have to use `hg amend` and make it one Diff without the ability to see intermediate Diffs.  Is this how Mercurial works, or is it just how the PR is set up for the Mercurial?  That is, it really can work like how GitHub works too? (I think the diffs are shown by Phabricator but I am not entirely sure).

Comment: How about squashing? You lose the benefit of seeing the incrementañ work, but you should see a single diff. I have no knowledge abiut `hg`, just in case.

Comment: but my intention is not about squashing something

Comment: Well.... it sounds like a UI problem, I guess there is not a big conceptual difference the way that revisions are put together in a branch between hg and git.

Comment: I wonder if a PR is a GitHub thing or a git thing... if hg or phabricator can also lump all the commits together as 1 PR, and then also let the reviewer see each diff out of the 12 diffs, then it should be the same as the PR in GitHub... but right now there seems to be no such function

Comment: Just to add a little bit more context, in pure git, for any revision, it's alwayd a full snapshot of the tree in each revision... so `the diffs` are a calculation that is performed on the fly. You could ask to show each one separately (`git log --patch HEAD~6..HEAD`) or it could be shown as a single diff (`git diff HEAD~6 HEAD`). As I said, it's a UI thing.

Comment: A PR is _not_ a git concept.

Comment: ok, so maybe it is not set up that way or I don't know how it can be done. But to speak of it this way, we can even say SVN can behave like that too, with the UI... they are just several diffs and we can lump them together as 1 PR, and let reviewer see all diffs as one, or see each intermediate diff

Comment: Definitely  it's a UI problem.

Comment: Don't use `hg amend`, that loses information on your individual changesets you'd get otherwise. If you use `hg` on the command line you can use `hg diff -r REVISION:tip` to show a single diff covering several revisions. That's what github essentially does, internally, too. I don't know Phabricator so I can't tell you if it is possible to, or how to, get it to display a single diff for several changesets.

Comment: I think you should drop the git and github tags. You're basically asking about using the Differential review system within Phabricator. According to https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/differential/ the recommended way to create review requests is to use Arcanist, so you might want to add [tag:arcanist], too. See also https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/arcanist_commit_ranges/

Answer (score 2):

1. PRs (and MRs) are just fully GitHub additions, didn't existed as separate entities in pure Git before, and have to be supported by git-clients due to "git is github", a common but completely erroneous notion today
2. `hg commit --amend` or `hg amend` from evolve **aren't** and **can't** be hg-equivalent of PRs *by concept* (squashing instead of adding external history)
3. In pure Mercurial-way you can use `hg in --bundle FILE FORK` for getting changes from FORK-URL and inspecting changes in form of set of changesets or as one changeset with relevant `hg diff` in GUI or console and pull (or drop bundle) into repo after review

Comment: so I wonder if in Phabricator, whether I can choose to view (1) all changes (example, all 6 commits) and (2) each intermediate commit just like on GitHub... it'd probably takes somebody who is familiar with Phabricator